# How to open url by clicking notification in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications, openurl

**##### when i click on notification the app reopens, i want to open a specific url after clicking the notification. #####**

![https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YIoLK3039IbtswnSdc5k7TKbp6UPhWKf] [see the image here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AL3f.png)

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Intent iA = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        iA.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,iA,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("FCM NOTIFICATION");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Comment: make pending intent broadcast, and then on that broadcast in receiver open URL

Comment: may this edited post will help you to understand my question.

Comment: instead of `.getActivity`, you can make a broadcast, then receive it with some broadcast receiver, and open URL in it. So basically nothing new in my comment. What is a problem? You don't know how to do broadcast?

Comment: yeah i don't know how to broadcast.

Comment: Asif Rahman shared even better way, check his answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use pending intent like this in your notification:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: It should work, may be you're not doing it the correct way. Btw your notification will not work in Oreo and higher devices as you haven't used notification channel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method like this one and just pass arguments

```
    void openUrl(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage, Context context, String title, String body, String commingUrl){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(commingUrl));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

and call the method inside `onMessageReceived` method ;like this just change with your variables

```
String title = Objects.requireNonNull(remoteMessage.getNotification()).getTitle();
    String text = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    String dataKey = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");                      
openAnotherApp(remoteMessage,getApplicationContext(),title,text, 
   remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
```